# How to call the multicall method?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I deployed two contracts on a local node with --dev running, the contract Token.sol is a standard ERC20 token contract：

```
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)public override returns (bool){
        _transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

//
    function encodeTransfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public pure returns (bytes memory){
        return abi.encodeWithSelector(this.transfer.selector, recipient, amount);
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256){
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }
```

Another contract Multicall.sol:

```
function multiCall(
        address[] calldata targets,
        bytes[] calldata data
    ) external returns (bytes[] memory) {
        require(targets.length == data.length, "target length != data length");

        bytes[] memory results = new bytes[](data.length);

        for (uint i; i < targets.length; i++) {
            (bool success, bytes memory result) = targets[i].call(data[i]);
            require(success, "call failed");
            results[i] = result;
        }

        return results;
    }
```

code I use to run the test：

```
   const encodeDataTransfer = await contract.methods.encodeTransfer(walletPoor, '100000').call();

    await contractMultical.methods.multiCall(
        [web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(contractAddress)],
        [encodeDataTransfer]
    )
        .call({
            from: walletRich, //owns enough tokens of Token.sol
            to: contractMultical,
            gas: toHex(gas),
            gasLimit : toHex(gas),
            //value : web3.utils.toWei('0.0001', 'ether'),
            //data: encodeData,
            maxFeePerGas : toHex(maxFeePerGas),
            maxPriorityFeePerGas : toHex(maxPriorityFeePerGas),
            //nonce : toHex(31)
        });
```

Error:

```
Error: Returned error: execution reverted: call failed
```

If I call the **transfer** method directly, everything works fine.

```
 const encodeData = await contract.methods.transfer(walletPoor, '100000')
    .call({
        from: walletRich,
        to: contractAddress,
        gas: toHex(gas),
        gasLimit : toHex(gas),
        //value : web3.utils.toWei('0.0001', 'ether'),
        //data: encodeData,
        maxFeePerGas : toHex(maxFeePerGas),
        maxPriorityFeePerGas : toHex(maxPriorityFeePerGas),
        //nonce : toHex(29)
    });
//this will return true
```

Where Did I miss?
Thanks

Comment: I think the issue might be that `encodeDataTransfer` is an encoded but not signed. In other words, when you invoke `multiCall`, *that* transaction is signed, but not the transactions that you have encoded and put into the array. Are you able to take `encodeDataTransfer`, then sign it with the appropriate account, *before* passing it into `multiCall`?

Comment: Sure I tried, since I run the geth node with --dev, so I signed the transaction with "eth_signTransaction" RPC, still not work